# Developing a Java Applet to restrict access to a particular directory tree

Tags: java, applet, ldap, x509

I am creating a Java based applet to secure a file system **directory**(Directory here stands for the folders) **tree** from being accessed directly. So that user can only use the files if he accesses them through the applet. For this I think to implement [X.500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.500) along with profiles of the user and using X.509 certificates to check their credentials. But I am not able to think how to make all this available through Java applet.
Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why? You don't say which LDAP implementation you are using, but certainly OpenLDAP can do that automatically based on the user identity. You don't need to write an applet for that, or at least if you do all you need is to give it a more privileged userID to log in with than users generally get access to.

Comment: Thanks for your input.I can use LDAP but as far as I hace read about it ,it can function only as white pages. Can it do the same with the entity objects being files and directories(file system)